# Как с помощью кода javascript открыть или перезагрузить devtools? Или прочитать об этом?

Tags: javascript

Хочу избежать ошибки:"Devtools was disconnected from the page. Once page is reloaded,DevTools will automatically reconnect." при обновлении chrome extension.

Comment: Когда это ошибка возникает? При обновлении какого расширения (могу только предполагать, что расширение для DevTools)? В чём негативные последствия этой ошибки, если переподключение происходит? *Хорошо сформулированный вопрос - это уже половина ответа.*

Comment: Расширение по типу(Extensions Reloader,Quick Extension Reload) для перезагрузки расширения. Все они используют chrome.management.getAll(function (extensions) {chrome.management.setEnabled()}.

Comment: Ваш комментарий не прояснил ситуацию. Приведите код и конкретно опишите где, когда, при каких обстоятельствах и с каких кодом у Вас возникает ошибка/проблема.